# Реализация интерфейсов Java

Tags: java, интерфейс

Столкнулся с проблемой - когда реализую в каком-то классе методы интерфейса Eclipse требует изменить их на public, хотя в реализуемом интерфейсе они без пометки public. 
Можете пояснить - почему так?

Comment: а на кой по вашему нужны интерфейсы с непубличныыми методами? Весь смысл интерфейса в том и состоит, что любой его реализующий класс гарантирует наличие у себя методов этого интерфейса

Answer (score 4):

В интерфейсе методы по-умолчанию публичны.

То есть

```java
public interface Foo {
  void bar();
}
```

равносильно

```java
public interface Foo {
  public void bar();
}
```

Т.к. интерфейс специфицирует набор доступных внешнему потребителю методов, которые должны быть реализованы классом, было бы странно делать их приватными.